# How to define the term closed-form expression?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does closed form solution usually mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9199/what-does-closed-form-solution-usually-mean)

The [Wikipedia article *Closed-form expression*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) states that such an expression can be defined "in terms of a bounded number of certain 'well-known' functions". I'm being confronted with an expression of the form $a_{n,k} = \sum_{i=0}^n(\mbox{closed-form expression in }i)$. Initially a recursive formula for the sequence $\{a_n\}$ of the form $a_n = (\mbox{closed-form expression in $a_n$})$ was given, so the sum is an explicit expression for the sequence. But would you also say, that it is a closed-form expression?

For every fixed $n$ it is a finite sum, so the number of certain "well-known" functions is bounded. But this is not valid for all $n$.

In this case, is the term *closed-form expression* clear without ambiguity? Could it be meant in both ways?

**Edit:** This might be confusing: of course for a fixed $n$ it's always easy to give a simple expression for $a_n$. For a fixed $n$ the expression for $a_n$ is just a number (even a natural number in my case). So the question is if the function $\sum$ is considered to be a "well-known" function. This might depend on the context, as answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9199/what-does-closed-form-solution-usually-mean). Usually such a sum won't be considered as closed-form, because often we search for a closed-form expression for such a sum.

Comment: The sum would not be ordinarily classified as a closed form, since the number of summands (terms) is unbounded, that is, could be arbitrarily large.

Comment: @lumbric Please see the cited prior question. If the answers and links there do not answer your question then please refine your question so to differentiate it.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks for the hint! I searched the archive, but couldn't find any similar question (I marked it as duplicated). The answers and comments there confirmed my suspicion, that it is not *always* meant to be a really precise term. Anyhow, I'll clarify my question a bit.