# Functions cannot be integrated as simple functions

Tags: calculus, integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you prove that a function has no closed form integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral)

Since I was a college student, I was told there were many functions that cannot be integrated as simple functions.(I'll give the definition of simple functions at the end of the article). As a TA for calculus now, I've been asked for integrated various functions, certainly, most of them are integrable(in the sense of simple functions). However, how could I know that certain functions are not integrable not merely because I cannot integrate them. (There was one time that one integration on the question sheet daunted all the TAs I asked).

Does anyone know THEORETICAL REASONS why certain functions cannot be integrated as simple funtions? Or could you refer to certain reference containing such materials? Or, could you show me by example, certain "good" function actually don't have "good" integration, I think one famous example could be  "$\frac{\sin x}{x}$".

**Simple functions**: 
The functions which is the summations(subtractions),multiplications(divisions), and compositions of the following functions(as well as the functions generated by these operations): $x, \sin x , \cos x, \log x, \sqrt[n]{x}, e^x$.

Comment: Relevant http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function

Comment: Seems to be a dupe of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/). [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9199/) is a related question.

Comment: Does $\log$ count as a "simply function"?  You may be interested in as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)

Comment: Yes, I have edited the article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A search for "integration in finite terms" will get you many useful results. This [paper](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~singer/ma792Kdocs/rosenlicht.pdf) by Rosenlicht is a very good place to start.

Bibliographic details: Maxwell Rosenlicht, Integration in Finite Terms, American Mathematical Monthly 79 (1972) 963-972.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is just what I am looking for!

Answer (score 2):

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)
Liouville's theorem which, by wikipedia, places an important restriction on antiderivatives that can be expressed as elementary functions