# Why we say this function have closed form while the other doesn't?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, closed-form

Why we say this function have closed form while the other doesn't?

$\int\sin(x)\ dx = -\cos(x) + C$ have a closed form

while $\int\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\ dx = \textrm{Si}(x) + C$ does not have a closed form?

Comment: Depends on your definition of closed. See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265780/how-to-determine-with-certainty-that-a-function-has-no-elementary-antiderivative

Comment: "No closed form" means "No expression that's as simple as I want it to be."

Comment: The Si function is expressible as a [hypergeometric function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricPFQ.html), another well known special function sometimes considered a closed form, so it is not “arbitrary”.

Answer (score 1):

"Closed form" isn't a generally accepted term. "In closed form" definitely means "in explicit finite terms". In addition to that, what a closed form is depends on the operations, functions and symbols you allow.
see [Wikipedia: Closed-form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression)

Some allow only [elementary expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) to be closed-form expressions. Therefore $\cos(x)$ is in closed form but $\textrm{Si}(x)$ not.

The most general definition of closed-form expressions allow all expressions in named operations/functions. With that definition, both $\cos(x)$ and $\textrm{Si}(x)$ are in closed form.

see also [What does closed form solution usually mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9199/what-does-closed-form-solution-usually-mean)