# Integrate $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{ka^2}{2m}-\frac{k}{m}x^2\:+\frac{kx^4}{2ma^2}}}dx$

Tags: integration, physics

For a physics assignment we are analyzing an anharmonic oscillator whose force is given by: $$ F =-kx + \frac{kx^3}{a^2},$$  where $k$ and $a$ are the spring constant and an arbitrary positive constant respectively. One of the questions is to find $x(t)$ for a particular initial velocity of $${v_0}^2 = \frac{ka^2}{2m}.$$ Separating variables I find that $${v(x)} = \sqrt{\frac{ka^2}{2m}-\frac{k}{m}x^2\:+\frac{kx^4}{2ma^2}}.$$  So then $x(t)$ is given by the integral in the title which I cannot solve, $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{ka^2}{2m}-\frac{k}{m}x^2\:+\frac{kx^4}{2ma^2}}}dx.$$ Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: My professor suggested using the identity $$\frac{2a}{a^2 -b^2} = \frac{1}{a-b} + \frac{1}{a+b},$$ and that the problem then becomes 'logarithimically easy'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just observe $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{ka^2}{2m}-\frac{k}{m}x^2\:+\frac{kx^4}{2ma^2}}}dx = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{k}{2ma^2}(x^2-a^2)^2}} dx$$ 
and then using substitution like $x = a \sin \theta$ to solve the integral ?

Comment: If I do that substitution I get an answer proportional to $\tanh(x/a)$, for positive x and a messy logarithm for general x. I'm satisfied with that answer but am still curious how to use my prof's hint. Do you see any way to use it? Thank you

Comment: Maybe you use that here $\frac{2a}{(a^2-x^2)}$ before you integrate ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a special function called [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral). For the integrand assuming the special form as in your problem, you are in luck since its coefficient in the denominator makes it a complete square, and you can use the answer provided by Sou.

Comment: But elliptic integrals don't have a closed form.

Comment: @A---B, [clearly we have different meanings for "closed form".](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/9203)